How to make columns in different rows have different widths?
This is my current HTML :


span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item-id {
  color: transparent;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.equipment_effect {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  place-items: center;
}
<table width=100% border=1>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 width=96 align=center style="padding: 0px;">
      <div style="position:relative; ">
        <img src="item_icon.png  width=96 style=" position:relative; z-index:1; " />
                <img src="sub_logo.png height=43 style="position:absolute;  z-index:2; left:0; bottom:0;" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan=6 align=center>Equipment Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=6 height=36 align=center>
      <div class="equipment_effect">
        <div>Effect1</div>
        <div>Effect2</div>
        <div>Effect3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7 align=center style="padding: 0px;">
      <table width=100% border=1 Frame=void>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan=2 width=20 align=center><img src="skill_logo.png" width=20></td>
          <td rowspan=2 width=40% align=center>Skill Name</td>
          <td rowspan=2 align=center>Skill Description1<br>Skill Description2<br>Skill Description3</td>
          <td align=center width=48><img src="attr.png" width=24></td>
          <td rowspan=2 width=72 align=center><img src="skill_icon.png" width=72></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align=center>Num</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



Table I want :

I use another borderless table to fill with the bottom section.
However, I heard that such a structure is not good, so I want to modify it.
I tried using colgroup to set the column width.


<table width=100% border=1>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 20px;" />
    <col style="width: 76px;" />
    <col style="width: calc(40% - 76px);" />
    <col/>
    <col style="width: 48px;" />
    <col style="width: 72px;" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2 align=center style="padding: 0px; table-layout: fixed; width: 96px;">
      <div style="position:relative; ">
        <img src="item_icon.png" width=96 style="position:relative;  z-index:1;" />
        <img src="sub_logo.png" height=43 style="position:absolute;  z-index:2; left:0; bottom:0;" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan=4 align=center>Equipment Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=4 height=36 align=center>
      <div class="equipment_effect">
        <div>Effect1</div>
        <div>Effect2</div>
        <div>Effect3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 align=center style="padding: 0px;"><img src="skill_logo.png" width=20></td>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2 align=center>Skill Name</td>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=1 align=center>Skill Description1<br>Skill Description2<br>Skill Description3</td>
    <td align=center><img src="attr.png" width=24></td>
    <td rowspan=2 align=center><img src="skill_icon.png" width=72></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=center>Num</td>
  </tr>
</table>



Table it shows :

But the result is little different from what I expected.(The width of "Skill Name" section is wider.) The width percentage is not working, or there might be other reasons?
Also, I noticed that the images slightly overlap the right border. Why??
Or should I use grid or flexbox to simulate a table to fill the bottom section?
Or is there a better and simpler way to achieve the style I want?

I used grid to simulate the inner table, replacing the original nested table, to achieve the style.


.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 40% auto 48px 72px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.area1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.area2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.area3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.area6 {
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.cells {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
}
<div class="table">
  <div class="cells area1">1</div>
  <div class="cells area2">2</div>
  <div class="cells area3">3</div>
  <div class="cells area4">4</div>
  <div class="cells area5">5</div>
  <div class="cells area6">6</div>
</div>



Although the purpose is done, I still hope to learn how to make an entire table have different column widths in different rows.

can you move from '90s to the new century in terms of coding? Tables are only for representing data. Your layout requires div and that way can be achieved easily enough

Yeah, I'm newbie and learning from 0

You can easily find more updated tutorials about responsive design using divs and media queries. This way you will learn directly the right way to do it
